# not able to write all the record in excel sheet using poi jar in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to save record fetched from the website in the excel sheet .i have 50 different records out which only last record is written in the excel 50 times. can u help me please
thanks to all

```
List<WebElement> xpath11 = m.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[contains(@id, 'rcmrow')]"));
int count = xpath11.size();
System.out.println(count);
for (WebElement link : xpath11) {
    String sd = link.getText();
    System.out.println(sd);
    File source = new File("/home/dev2/Desktop/readexcell.xlsx");
    FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(source);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("data");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        XSSFRow excelRow = sheet.createRow(i);
        XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(0);
        excelCell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
        excelCell.setCellValue(sd);
    }

    wb.write(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the excel file for every `WebElement` in the outer `for` loop, and write its text over and over in the inner `for` loop. You need to create the file before the `for` and use only one loop

```
File source = new File("/home/dev2/Desktop/readexcell.xlsx");
FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(source);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("data");

List<WebElement> xpath11 = m.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[contains(@id, 'rcmrow')]"));
int count = xpath11.size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String sd = xpath11.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(sd);
    XSSFRow excelRow = sheet.createRow(i);
    XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(0);
    excelCell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
    excelCell.setCellValue(sd);
}

wb.write(input);
```